# I need to parse or extract a string from a field called token nested in a JSON object in order to replace email and password for a session token

Tags: node.js, json, authentication, zapier

I am trying to create a session auth token that can be used for subsequent api calls after the user enters their email and password.

With the first piece of code showed below, i am getting a 200 response for correct email and password, but i am getting an error because i am not able to grab "token" from the second piece of code i shared below...

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://api.knack.com/v1/applications/5e159b77ed2cc100162fae1f/session',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Knack-Application-Id': '5e159b77ed2cc100162fae1f',
    'email': bundle.authData.email,
    'password': bundle.authData.password
  },
  params: {
     'email': bundle.authData.email,
    'password': bundle.authData.password

  },
  body: {
    'email': bundle.authData.email,
    'password': bundle.authData.password

  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content.token);
    //const token = z.JSON.parse(reponse.content.token)
   // const token=

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return {
      'sessionKey': results.token
    };
  });
```

The response from above successfully authenticated a 200 response, and provided a JSON object which contains user profile information AND THE TOKEN, which i need to take. I am unable to grab the necessary string from the JSON response (because i am a noob), which looks like this:

```
// Data returned by remote login request
{
  "session": {
    "user": {
      "approval_status": "approved",
      "empty_pass": false,
      "id": "user_id",
      "profile_keys": [
        "profile_4"
      ],
      "profile_objects": [
        {
          "entry_id": "entry_id",
          "object": "object_4"
        }
      ],
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNTUzMWExNmI2YTEzMTk1ZTcyNmUxZTBmIiwiYXBwbGljYXYpb25faWQiOiI1NTIzMTM5ZjNiY2U2NDdhMDJiZDUxNTAiLCJpYXQiOjE0Mjk3MTgzNzl9.K-WULiJxT-st8vxnTkqxCtp2nv5ykrSToPQsTRx6r1I",
      "utility_key": "key",
      "values": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the string from the "token" field.

Show me the way, if you may?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the contents of the `response` variable! If that is the object you're getting back, you should be able to access the `token` field using the following code:

```
const response = {
  "session": {
    "user": {
      "approval_status": "approved",
      "empty_pass": false,
      "id": "user_id",
      "profile_keys": [
        "profile_4"
      ],
      "profile_objects": [
        {
          "entry_id": "entry_id",
          "object": "object_4"
        }
      ],
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNTUzMWExNmI2YTEzMTk1ZTcyNmUxZTBmIiwiYXBwbGljYXYpb25faWQiOiI1NTIzMTM5ZjNiY2U2NDdhMDJiZDUxNTAiLCJpYXQiOjE0Mjk3MTgzNzl9.K-WULiJxT-st8vxnTkqxCtp2nv5ykrSToPQsTRx6r1I",
      "utility_key": "key",
      "values": {}
    }
  }
}

console.log(response.session.user.token);
eyJ0eXAiOiJK...
```

You can use `.` to reference a key used by a JavaScript object. So if your variable is `response`, you can get the `session` object inside of it using `response.session`, and you can get the `user` object inside of `session` with `response.session.user`.

However, first, you probably want to change the contents of the `then` block to this:

```
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response);

    return {
      'sessionKey': results.session.user.token
    };
```

The `z.JSON.parse` function will convert the response data into something that JavaScript can use natively. If `response` has the format referenced above, you can use that dot notation to get at each inner object. Your first example is passing `response.content.token` which doesn't seem to exist. Try using `response` instead and see if that gets you closer.

This page might give you some more context to help you tease out some of the fields inside that response object: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Good luck!

Comment: Hi i appreciate your reply! I tried to use "console.log(response.session.user.token);" and it says response undefined.

I also tried it in with use case on Zapier and it says: 

Received content "{"session":{"user":{"id":"5e159b7a6e933c7c6139454c","values":{"field_7":["profile_4","profile_5","pr" Cannot read property 'user' of undefined Console logs:

Comment: Oops, thanks for clarifying! I've edited the answer above to provide some more context. Try replacing `z.JSON.parse(response.content.token)` with `z.JSON.parse(response)` and `'sessionKey': results.token` with `'sessionKey': results.session.user.token` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, i get the response 200 for initial authentication now im thrown a new error:

 {"id":"5e159b7a6e933c7c6139454c","values":{"field_7":["profile_4","profile_5","pr" Error parsing response. "[object Object]" is not a string. Console logs:

Comment: If it's crashing in the same code, my best guess here is that you don't actually need to use `z.JSON.parse`. You could try omitting the line that reads `const results = z.JSON.parse(response);` and change `'sessionKey': results.session.user.token` to `'sessionKey': response.session.user.token`.